# Showing if two quadratic forms on a vector space be represented as multiples of each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, representation-theory

Consider an $F$-vector space with dimension two ($F$ is an algebraically closed field). If I take two quadratic forms $q_1, q_2$ such that $q_1^{-1}(0) = q_2^{-1}(0) = 0$. Is it possible to show that for some $c \in F^{\times}$, we could write $q_1 = c q_2$? I know this doesn't hold if we're dealing with $F=R$. But, will it hold for any other field with a characteristic of other than two?

Edit: A similar question is answered at [Quadratic Forms on a (finite dimensional real) vector space with same zero set are scalar multiples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743404/quadratic-forms-on-a-finite-dimensional-real-vector-space-with-same-zero-set-a)  But, my question concerns quadratic forms on an $F$-vector space where $F$ is a field with characteristic other than two and not necessarily on finite dimensional real vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension $d >1$ with this property and only assume that $|F| \geq 4$. In other words, the space of quadratic forms that do not vanish outside zero is a line (minus zero). Let $q$ be such a nonzero quadratic form. For any $A \in GL(V)$, $q \circ A$ is a quadratic form that vanishes only at zero, so $q \circ A=\lambda_A q$, and $A \longmapsto \lambda_A$ is a group homomorphism, so that $\lambda_A=f(\det{A})$ where $f$ is an endomorphism of $F^*$.

In particular, if $A \in SL(V)$, then $q \circ A=q$. But for any nonzero $x \in V$, there is some $A \in SL(V)$ mapping $x$ to $\lambda x$ with $\lambda^2\neq 1$. Then $q(x)=(q \circ A)(x)=q(\lambda x)=\lambda^2 q(x)$ so $q(x)=0$, hence a contradiction.